# Job title in reports but title in user interface and in back end

Tags: apex, administration

standard field title on contact object   when am running in the standard reports(Account and contact) am able to see as job title in standard report and in page layout detail page.
but in edit page layout, In fields section,fieldlevelsecurity every where showing   label as title

so my question is what is the label for title field?

Comment: Please answer it otherwise help whats wrong in the question instead of voting down

Comment: Please edit your post to include important details like what object(s) are you reporting on, is "outofbox" a custom field, if you are using standard or custom report types, if custom did you include  the field in the report type?

Comment: Yes i have included in report and able to see as job title but in UI I mean in edit page layout as title

Comment: If its a formula field, it wont be visible in edit layout

Answer (score 1):

If you want to know the label of the `Contact.Title` field, run this script:

```
system.debug(Contact.Title.getDescribe().getLabel());
```

For me, the output is:

> DEBUG|Title

However, these labels can be changed in a given organization, so no one can answer this question for the specific org you are looking at except you.

Comment: Got it thanks for me output is Job Title